# Check the packages installed in interactive mode

Tags: python

I installed multiple packages and `pip list` them from command line,

However, when I try to import them, constantly remind me:

```
ModuleNotFoundError: No module name
```

How to check the packages installed from the interactive mode (like in ipython)?

Comment: Have you got multiple versions of python installed?

Comment: Yes, `pip3 install` and `pip3 list`,

Comment: Do you use a virtualenv?

Comment: No @LutzHorn I installed a python3.6 months ago and install Anaconda days ago.

Comment: Use `pip3 install` the packages